# Number of heads at the end

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are $8$ coins, which are flipped simultaneously. Coins that show tails are flipped a second time. If $Y$ is the RV that represents the number of heads after the second set of flips, find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\mathrm{Var}[Y]$.

Can this be modeled as a binomial distribution with $n = 8$ and $p = \frac{3}{4}$, thus giving me $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 6$ and $\mathrm{Var}[Y] = \frac{3}{2}$?

**EDIT:** My logic was that the only outcomes for a coin are $\{H, TH, TT\}$, and the only way to fail was to get $TT$, which has a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. So any given coin has a $\frac{3}{4}$ probability of succeeding.

Comment: Let $X$ and $Z$ be the number of heads in the first and second set of flips, respectively. Both $X$ and $Z$ are binomially distributed. ($Y=X+Z$).

Comment: But how would you know the number of trials in Z?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it can modelled as proposed, your reasoning is entirely correct.
And among the quickest tracks towards the seeked values.